# How to plot a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, intuition, visualization

We cannot plot graph of a complex function $f:\mathbb {C\to C}$ as it requires $4$ dimensions.But we can show how the mapping transforms the domain plane into image plane.We can draw grid lines parallel and perpendicular to $x$-axis and see how the grid lines are modified.But often it becomes tedious task to plot these kind of diagrams.Is there any systematic procedure to draw such figures without help of any software?

For example , $z^2,z^3,\sin(z),\log(z),\exp(z)$ etc.

I want a method to visualize any given function.Is there a way out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without help of any software?

Comment: @lhf yes,without software would be better,but I won't mind if you suggest me some software other than wolframalpha.

Comment: Very hard to do by hand. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40308/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236021/is-it-possible-to-graph-complex-zeros-of-a-polynomial

Comment: Not an answer, but [possibly of interest](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/software/Mappings/index.html).

Comment: There's another site that does the job. Functions of $z$ could be entered. http://davidbau.com/conformal/#iz%5E2-1%2Bexp(z)%2F10

Comment: The grid lines keep one of the coordinates fixed, and the other coordinate acts as the parameter of a parametric equation, which you can eliminate. E.g.

$$z\to z^2\leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x=u^2-V^2,\\y=2uV\end{cases}\leftrightarrow x=\frac{y^2}{4V^2}-V^2,$$ a family of parabolas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some years ago, I have written a simple script in Python that can do it ... May be it can help you ? This just needs a  (free) python distribution :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func(z):
    return z**2


def plot_conformal_map(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, nb_grid, nb_points):
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nb_grid), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nb_points))
    xv = np.transpose(xv)
    yv = np.transpose(yv)

    zv = func(xv + 1j*yv)
    uv = np.real(zv)
    vv = np.imag(zv)



    xh, yh = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nb_points), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, nb_grid))

    zh = func(xh + 1j*yh)
    uh = np.real(zh)
    vh = np.imag(zh)


    ax = plt.subplot(121)
    for i in range(len(yv)):
        ax.plot(xv[i], yv[i], 'b-', lw=1)
        ax.plot(xh[i], yh[i], 'r-', lw=1)

    ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
    for i in range(len(vv)):
        ax2.plot(uv[i], vv[i], 'b-', lw=1)
        ax2.plot(uh[i], vh[i], 'r-', lw=1)

    plt.show()


nb_grid = 9
nb_points = 30

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -1, 1, -1, 1

plot_conformal_map(func, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, nb_grid, nb_points)
```

And the output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0d1j.jpg

Comment: This is a mathematics site, not a programming or software implementation site.

Comment: You can delete my answer if needed but the author seems to be ok with any suggestion of software. Python is commonly used to plot functions.  Sorry if it is not the answer expected.

Comment: Comment to asker: "Without the help of software?"  Response from asker: "yes,without software would be better"  Not everyone in math is fluent in python.

Comment: @ZosoLedZep it's ok.It helped a lot.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar, 
glad to have been able to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Another popular way for plotting complex functions is [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring), which associates brightness with the modules of $f(z)$ and hue with its argument.

I recently write [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot), a Python package which makes creating these plots easy. For example, for the natural log:

[image]

```
import cplot
import numpy as np

plt = cplot.plot(np.log, (-2.0, +2.0, 400), (-2.0, +2.0, 400))
plt.show()
```

[cplot's gallery](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot#gallery) has many more cool examples.